# Limit number of recorded triggers while keeping the receiving order

Tags: c++, oop

There is a use case where there are received different types of triggers and the requirements are

1. Have only 5 records of the same trigger, and override the oldest one in case of new trigger received while 5 records are available
2. The order of triggers should be reserved.
3. maintaining first come first go concept of queue
4. be able to remove single trigger anywhere in the records while maintaining the order.

```
        template <typename T, std::size_t kSize>
        class kqueue
        {
        private:
            // main queue mutex
            std::mutex m_mainMutex;
    
            // array of mutex to disable data racing on queues
            std::array<std::mutex, kSize> m_mutexArray;
    
            // number of queues inside a queueu
            uint32_t K;
    
            // main queue that holds all data
            // T stands for data type
            // uint8_t is the data type for sub queue number
            std::vector<std::pair<T, uint8_t> > m_mainQueue;
    
            // Array of sub queues to hold the positions of each sub queue data
            // in the main queue.
            std::array<std::queue<uint8_t> , kSize> m_subQueues;
        public:
            virtual kqueue();
            virtual ~kqueue();
            // void push(T Data);
            void pop();
            bool isEmpty();
            void pushToK(uint8_t K, T Data);
            void popFromK(uint8_t K);
            bool isKEmpty(uint8_t K);
            std::vector<std::pair<T, uint8_t>::iterator front() const;
        }; // end of class kqueue
```

```
template <>
kqueue::kqueue()
{
}

// main class destructor "can be overridden"
kqueue::~kqueue()
{
}
// /* this function isn't right as the push function isn't identifying which sub queue to push in */
// template <typename T>
// void kqueue::push(T Data)
// {
//     std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(m_mainMutex);
//     m_mainQueue.emplace_back(Data);
// }

template <>
void kqueue::pop()
{
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(m_mainMutex);
    
    m_mainQueue.erase(m_mainQueue.begin());
}

template <typename T>
void kqueue::pushToK(uint8_t K, T Data)
{
    const std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(m_mutexArray[K]);
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(m_mainMutex);
        m_mainQueue.emplace_back(Data, K);
    }
}

template <>
void kqueue::popFromK(uint8_t K)
{
    // locks targeted mutex to prevent data racing on such queue
    const std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(m_mutexArray[K]);
    {
       const std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(m_mainMutex);
       for (auto i = m_mainQueue.begin(); i != m_mainQueue.end() ; i++)
       {
           if( std::get<1>(*i) == K)
           {
               m_mainQueue.erase(i);
               m_mainQueue.shrink_to_fit();
               break;
           }
       }
    }
}

template <>
bool kqueue::isEmpty()
{
    return m_mainQueue.empty();
}

template <>
bool kqueue::isKEmpty(uint8_t K)
{
    return m_subQueues[K].empty();
}

template <>
std::vector<std::pair<T, uint8_t>::iterator kqueue::front() const
{
    const std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(m_mainMutex);
    return m_mainQueue.begin();
}
```

Comment: What is your question? Why does the queue have subqueues?

Comment: You have a virtual constructor…?

Comment: @DavisHerring It is of course a syntax issue, I am just adding a template with its all issues in order to explain so you can help me.

Comment: @Quimby I want to have a queue of sub queues to maintain the order of first come first go and also if I wanted to pop out a single data from a sub queue it is removed from main queue without affecting the main queue order "still first come first go".